# Why is $r(\theta) = \frac{1}{\| \theta \|}$ here?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, spherical-coordinates

> Why is $$r(\theta) = \frac{1}{\| \theta \|}$$ for $\theta \in S^{n-1}$, where $S^{n-1}$ is the $n-1$ dimensional unit spherical shell?

This is part of the following extract, which I'm a little lazy to type (so I'm putting a screenshot):
[image]

"**since $r(\theta)$ is the largest number $r$ for which $r\theta \in K$**" - *why is this true, and how does it help?*

By the way, we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and using spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: Just putting euclidean norm makes it $r(\theta)\equiv 1$ which would be silly. so can you clarify?

Comment: Yeah, the euclidean norm definitely does that. I think we are working with euclidean norms only though (or not?)! See Page 8 here: http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf @CalvinKhor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier in the notes, Prof. Ball states that the notation $|\cdot|$ is reserved for the Euclidean norm. So here he must be talking about something else. It should be the norm $\|\cdot\|_K$; in this specific instance he is talking about the norm given by $K=$ the just mentioned octahedron, i.e. the $\ell^1$ norm $\|x\|=\sum_1^n |x_i|$.

It seems that definitionally, $r(\theta)$ is  the "radius of $K$ in direction $\theta$", namely the largest $r\ge0$ such that $r\theta \in K$. From $K = \{x\in \mathbb R^n : \|x\| \le 1\}$, it should be easy to see that all the points $r(\theta)\theta$ correspond to the boundary of the ball
$$ \partial K = \partial \{x\in \mathbb R^n : \|x\| \le 1\} = \{x\in \mathbb R^n : \|x\|=1\}= \{ r(\theta)\theta : \theta\in S^{n-1}\} $$
Thus, letting $x=r(\theta)\theta$ be a general point of $\partial K$, on taking norms,
$$ 1 = r(\theta)\|\theta\|$$
hence the result.

The context that would be missing from your question without the screenshot is that this is strongly dependent on the choice of $K$. if $\|x\|=|x|$ was indeed the euclidean norm, then the radius would be identically 1, which does indeed correspond to the unit ball in said norm.

Comment: So $\partial K$ refers to the boundary of $K$? Is this convention?

Comment: It is *my* convention and certainly standard in topology at least, and I did mean it in the topological sense. I have not read these notes past page 8. @strawberry-sunshine

Comment: Great, many thanks!